# hibernate not work in 18.04 LTS how to fix it?

Tags: 18.04, power-management, hibernate

I can't set **swap** memory on my **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**. But I can't found **hibernate** option my Ubuntu. I am trying and tired but not get any solution please help me about it. Thank you